# sys.argv not printing the right output after arguments are given

Tags: python

So I have tried to implement sys.argv in my code to run it in cmd. The problem is that its not working and i suspect it has to do with wrong index (new to python). Ive tried this method on other programs and its working normally, but when i try to do it in this code its not working. You basically have to give 2 arguments, a path to a directory and a keyword. The program will then print to you in which files it can be found in. When im using normal inputs() its working fine, but with the command line arguments its not printing the files it can be found in. Here is the code:

```
from pathlib import Path as path
import sys


mapp_input = sys.argv[1]

mapp = path(mapp_input).glob("**/*")

keyword = sys.argv[2]

keyword_files = []

for Path in mapp:
    if Path.is_file():
        with Path.open('r') as file:
            try:
                for line in file.readlines():
                    if keyword in line:
                        keyword_files.append(str(Path))

            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                pass

keyword_files = "\n".join(keyword_files)
print("Keyword found in :", "\n", keyword_files)
```

This is the output i get in cmd, not showing the file it can be found in:

[image: I enter the path as argument 1 and the keyword as argument 2 (which is apple) Still not printing the file it can be found in]

Comment: have you examined what `mapp` looks like within the script

Comment: No, how do I do that? :)

Comment: What are the arguments/inputs? Can you share the full command you are running including the script and the args?

Comment: I will edit my post and show you it there @IainShelvington

Comment: Edited my post now :D @IainShelvington

Comment: @AhmedMourad So `mapp_input` is that path ending in "Inlamning" and `keyword` is "6"? You're passing another arg "apple" but ignoring it?

Comment: exactly what i thought. But the path name ends with "inlamning 6" (with a space between them) and apple is the keyword. I tried to change the index of apple to 3 but it still doesnt work :(

Comment: Wrap the path in quotes or prefix the space with backslash `path\ 6` so that it is a single argument instead of two. Arguments are separated by spaces

Comment: Wrapped it in quotes and it worked as it should, Thank you so much!